# Translate website into different language

Tags: web, translation

How can I convert my website into different language, for ex I want to translate it into Russian. It is a commercial website, i cant use google translate. How can I do it please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Hire an translator? If its for commercial use I doubt that there are any online tools that are good enough, and there is nothing less trustworthy than misspelled websites asking for credit card information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many articles in codeproject that can help you achieve this, refer to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Internationalization.aspx), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Kb/aspnet/localizationByVivekTakur.aspx), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/locale/Run_net_application_in_a.aspx), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GlobalizingLocalizing.aspx) and several others. Try searching ASP.NET Globalization or ASP.NET Culture in google and stackoverflow, you'll find several articles and posts. Of course, nothing beats the old fashion way of translating ;) I agree with MSI and Christopher, hiring a translator is the best solution to your problem (that's what we did for our website). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I Don't think for such a scenario you can use any automatic translator tools available as none of them can render a perfect translation. Your best bet is to get a translator and create a separate version of the website.

I was wondering by the way, is that a c# question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Hire a translator. If you want a quality product, it really is that simple.